# Hugginface Multi-Class classification using AutoModelForSequenceClassification

Tags: deep-learning, pytorch, huggingface-transformers, loss-function, multiclass-classification

I am trying to use Hugginface's `AutoModelForSequenceClassification` API for multi-class classification but am confused about its configuration.

My dataset is in one hot encoded and the problem type is multi-class (one label at a time)

What I have tried:

```
from transformers import AutoModelForSequenceClassification

model = AutoModelForSequenceClassification.from_pretrained("bert-base-uncased",
                                                           num_labels=6,
                                                           id2label=id2label,
                                                           label2id=label2id)



batch_size = 8
metric_name = "f1"



from transformers import TrainingArguments, Trainer

args = TrainingArguments(
    f"bert-finetuned-english",
    evaluation_strategy = "epoch",
    save_strategy = "epoch",
    learning_rate=2e-5,
    per_device_train_batch_size=batch_size,
    per_device_eval_batch_size=batch_size,
    num_train_epochs=10,
    weight_decay=0.01,
    load_best_model_at_end=True,
    metric_for_best_model=metric_name,
    #push_to_hub=True,
)


trainer = Trainer(
    model,
    args,
    train_dataset=encoded_dataset["train"],
    eval_dataset=encoded_dataset["test"],
    tokenizer=tokenizer,
    compute_metrics=compute_metrics
)
```

Is it correct?

I am confused about the loss function, when I am printing one forward pass the loss is `BinaryCrossEntropyWithLogitsBackward`

```
SequenceClassifierOutput([('loss',
                           tensor(0.6986, grad_fn=<BinaryCrossEntropyWithLogitsBackward0>)),
                          ('logits',
                           tensor([[-0.5496,  0.0793, -0.5429, -0.1162, -0.0551]],
                                  grad_fn=<AddmmBackward0>))])
```

which is used for multi-label or binary classification tasks. It should use 'nn.CrossEntropyLoss' ? How to properly use this API for multiclass and define the loss function?

Answer (score 0):

You have six classes, with values 1 or 0 in each cell for encoding. For example, a tensor [0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 0.]  is representation a fifth class. Our task is predict  six labels([1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.] ) and compare them with ground truth([0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 0.] ). For training we use loss function BinaryCrossEntropyWithLogitsBackward

Comment: That problem statement is Multiclass, Not MultiLabel.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

You need to set `problem_type="multi_label_classification"` in `AutoModelForSequenceClassification.from_pretrained` like so:

```py
model = AutoModelForSequenceClassification.from_pretrained("bert-base-uncased",
                                                           num_labels=6,
                                                           problem_type="multi_label_classification"
                                                           id2label=id2label,
                                                           label2id=label2id)
```

Make sure your labels are defined as [b, n] where b is the batch size and n is the amount of classes, all floats. For example, if a record has a total of 6 labels, and first and the last are correct for this record, the label should be: `[1.0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.0]`